# How to get a list of git repositories from bit bucket to be used as variables in bash script?

Tags: git, bash, repository, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am trying to write a bash script that takes all of the repositories I have on bitbucket and backs them up locally.

I am stuck trying to get a list of repos from bitbucket. I have read a little bit of their api that does this, and I even tested it. But it's just so massive that I just don't know where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check ["GET a list of repositories for an account"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/repositories-endpoint-423626330.html#repositoriesEndpoint-GETalistofrepositoriesforanaccount) API. It is pretty straightforward to use it with `curl`:

```
curl -u '<user>:<password>' https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<owner>
```

The `owner` may be the same as `user`. Note, that if you are going to query only public repositories, you don't need any authorization (`-u` option). The response is paginated, so you may need to make multiple calls.

This API returns a JSON object describing all *visible* (for authenticated user) repos of `owner`. One of the ways to parse it in Bash is to use [`jsawk`](https://github.com/micha/jsawk). But you are free to use any tool you are comfortable with like NodeJS or Python. You'll just need to read from `stdin` and parse it as JSON. Simple example, just to start with. Fetches all public repos of [jespern](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/):

```
curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/jespern | jsawk 'return this.values.map(value => value.full_name)'

["jespern/cx","jespern/cx-patches","jespern/ldap2vcard","jespern/pyetsy","jespern/puck","jespern/hgswitch","jespern/smart-oxe","jespern/pygments-anchorlinenos","jespern/emptyrepo","jespern/help"]
```

At this point you can use `sed` or `awk` to extract them from the array.

Comment: I ended up using grep to sort through the JSON to get just the names.